# Livereload gulp not working when in separate terminal

Tags: gulp, livereload, gulp-livereload

I am having difficulties with livereload in my gulp file.

If I run `livereload.listen()` as part of my watch task it works.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.less', ['less']);
});

// run gulp watch
```

However, if I launch live reload as separate task in another term window before watch it does not work.

```
gulp.task('lr', function() {
  livereload.listen();
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.less', ['less']);
});
```

// run gulp lr in one terminal and gulp watch in another - after.

I've tried using the `gulp-connect` plugin with the same result. Something about the watch task being run separately. I can see livereload loaded in the browser in all cases and watch runs correctly.

What is happening and is it possible to run these as 2 tasks (note that I am not interested in joining the tasks as one. That's not the goal of this question).